# Jacobi iteration method

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to find solution for this ex. using Jacobi method
[image: test example]

So i just write simple code for this case

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   int n = 100;
   double x[n], y[n], z[n], q[n];

   x[0]=0.0;
   y[0]=0.0;
   z[0]=0.0;
   q[0]=0.0;

   for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
     x[i+1] = 29.0/5.0 - (2.0*y[i])/5.0 - z[i]/5.0 - q[i]/5.0;
     y[i+1] = 31.0/6.0 - (2.0*x[i])/6.0 - (2.0*z[i])/6.0 - q[i]/6.0;
     z[i+1] = 26.0/7.0 - x[i]/7.0 - (2.0*y[i])/7.0 - q[i]/7.0;
     q[i+1] = 19.0/8.0 - x[i]/8.0 - y[i]/8.0 - (2*z[i])/8.0;

     cout<<"\tx="<<x[i+1]<<"\ty="<<y[i+1]<<"\tz="<<z[i+1]<<"\tq="<<q[i+1]<<"\n";

   }

   return 0;
 }
```

And it's not working! As you can see even after 10(20, 30) iterations it must look like solution
[image: iterations and results]

But here's what I got ($n = 20$)

[image]

Look at $z$ (which is $x_3$ value)
What's wrong?

Comment: Arguably it's better to develop your algorithms first in python + numpy or Matlab, and only later write them in C if you need more speed.

Comment: @littleO does it matter which language to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this Matlab code and got the same answer you got.  So I think your code is correct.

```
A = [5 2 1 1; 2 6 2 1; 1 2 7 1; 1 1 2 8];
b = [29 31 26 19]';

B = A - diag(diag(A));
D = diag(A);

xn = zeros(size(b));

for n = 1:20

    xn = (b - B*xn)./D;

end
```

Edit: The correct solution computed using Matlab's backslash operator agrees with the solution your code came up with.

```
EDU>> A\b

ans =

   3.992753623188405
   2.954106280193237
   2.161835748792270
   0.966183574879227
```

Whoever wrote this problem meant for the right hand side of the equation to be $\begin{bmatrix} 29 \\ 31 \\ 25 \\19 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: well, but why is there such big observational errors?

Comment: The "solution" is not correct.  Your code is working.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the solution given by Matlab's backslash operator.

Comment: Well, yes, code works but how to make it solve it right? 
Is there some more codtitions which I should to check?

Comment: What I meant is that your answer key has an error, but your code is fine.

Comment: Damn, thanks! This problem is from one old soviet book about iteration methods :)